# Label Error AX 2012

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to create a label in AX but even though the label ID is created and selected I still get this error

> Cannot create a label without creating label ID first

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Please provide more Information in your question so that we can help you: What version of AX are you using? Are your label files version controlled? In what method is the error generated? Also please take the time to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you,I will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to [create a label file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/aa844896.aspx) (or use one provided for you), then set the preferred label prefix in the setup tab page of [the label editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa617477.aspx) before [creating the first label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa620083.aspx).

Comment: Actually it was permission problem,I needed to be in a lower level to be able to edit.Thank you anyway I will need this